# Logic of multiple filter statements of CALCULATE() in DAX

Tags: dax, daxstudio

I'm fairly new to DAX and I curious to how DAX evaluates multiple filter parameters if supplied to `CALCULATE()` and `CALCULATETABLE()`.

Please consider the following statements:

DAX statement 1:

```
Net Sales ACT = CALCULATE(
                          SUMX('Fact', 'Fact'[Gross Sales] - 'Fact'[Costs]),
                          FILTER('Fact', 'Fact'[Scenario Key] = LOOKUPVALUE(Scenario[Scenario Key], Scenario[Scenario], "Actual"))
                          )
```

DAX statement 2:

```
Net Sales ACT LY = CALCULATE(
                             [Net Sales ACT],
                             SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date])
                             )
```

DAX statement 3:

```
Net Sales ACT LY = 

VAR
    v_lookup = FILTER(
                      'Fact',
                      'Fact'[Scenario Key] = LOOKUPVALUE(Scenario[Scenario Key], Scenario[Scenario], "Actual")
                      )

RETURN  -- << why does this chained filter not produce the same results as in statement 2?
        CALCULATE(
                  SUMX('Fact', 'Fact'[Gross Sales] - 'Fact'[Costs]),
                  v_lookup, 
                  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date])
                  )
```

The relationships:

[image]

The results generated vary widely, with statement 2 giving the correct output. I can't wrap my head around exactly why statement 3 doesn't work.

My question is simple, how come DAX does not compute the same values for statement 2 and statement 3? My belief was that if I supplied multiple filters to `CALCULATE()` these would be applied to the same `filter context`. However this does not seem to be the case, how does this exactly work?

Thanks!

Comment: consider that: IN Statement2 you have Calculate inside Calculate and this change a lot.
A really good article about CALCULATE:
https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2010/01/03/how-calculate-works-in-dax/

Comment: Yes. However statement 3 should evaluate to the same results given that the filters are applied together?

Comment: It should not. First, you premade a variable ( Table Variable -> and put this as a filter, and this part is calculated independent), in statement2 you have two Filter statements, and I almost certain here come AUTO-EXIST (which is counterintuitive) in statemnt3 it's not fired.

You should watch Alberto and his explanations.
https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/auto-exist-on-clusters-or-numbers-unplugged-22/